# How to bind a Python socket to a specific domain?

Tags: python, sockets, heroku

I have a Heroku application that has a domain `moarcatz.tk`. It listens for non-HTTP requests using Python's `socket`.
The documenatation states that if I bind a socket to an empty string as an IP address, it will listen on all available interfaces. I kept getting empty requests from various IP addresses, so I assume that setting the socket to only listen for connections to `moarcatz.tk` would fix the problem. But I don't know how to bind a socket to a domain name.
I tried `'moarcatz.tk`' and `gethostbyname('moarcatz.tk')`, but both give me this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

What's up with that?

Comment: You can not bind a listening socket to a DNS hostname, only to an IP address or an interface.

Comment: @KlausD. So how could I make sure I only get requests directed to `moarcatz.tk`?

Comment: Strictly speaking, you can't. Application level protocols like HTTP can give you some information about the domain name used to get the IP address (e.g., the Host header), but that is not guaranteed to be correct, and can be spoofed. At the socket/transport level, that information is not sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't control this via your code, but you can control this via Heroku.

Heroku has a pretty nifty DNS CNAME tool you can use to ensure your app ONLY listens to incoming requests for specific domains -- it's part of the core Heroku platform.

What you do is this:

```
heroku domains:add www.moarcatz.tk
```

Then, go to your DNS provider for `moarcatz.tk` and add a CNAME record for:

```
www <heroku-app-name>.herokuapp.com
```

This will do two things:

- Point your DNS to Heroku.
- Make Heroku filter the incoming traffic and ALLOW it for that specific domain.